# Grouping datatable causing null reference exception in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Hi i have a query which run with no problem

```
 var v = (from r in cTable.AsEnumerable()
         group r by r.Field<string>("Name") into g
         select new
         {
            CallType = g.Key,
            Count = g.Count()
         });
```

This runs quite good. But when i make change by adding

```
 var v = (from r in cTable.AsEnumerable()
         group r by r.Field<string>("Name").Replace(",", "") into g
         select new
         {
            CallType = g.Key,
            Count = g.Count()
         });
```

It gives me `Object Refrenence not set to instance errror` Why so ? I just wanna any comma in name column should be avoid in grouping the data i.e 'Rajeev' and Ra,jeev' should be count as 'Rajeev' while grouping

Comment: So what's the value of `strColumn`? are you sure it's `Name` at the time you test?

Comment: it looks like at least one element `r.Field<string>("Name")` is null.

Comment: @KingKing that surely may be the case, How can i make check here for ignoring null values while grouping the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for a safe solution:

```
var v = from r in cTable.AsEnumerable()
        let name = r.Field<string>("Name")
        group r by (name ?? "").Replace(",", "") into g
        select new {
          CallType = g.Key,
          Count = g.Count()
        };
```

Note that with the above code, all the null or empty strings will be grouped into the same group. If you want to filter out all the null values, just add some where like this:

```
var v = from r in cTable.AsEnumerable()
        let name = r.Field<string>("Name")
        where name != null
        group r by name.Replace(",", "") into g
        select new {
          CallType = g.Key,
          Count = g.Count()
        };
```

Comment: `Invalid Term or expression')'`

Comment: @RajeevKumar updated, it's because I copied your code. Just remove the last `)` right before the last `;`

Answer (score 1):

Check Null before grouping using Ternary operator, you can replace null with some string e.g. " or empty string whatever term you want to use for showing null group key

```
var v = (from r in cTable.AsEnumerable()
        group r by r.Field<string>("Name") == null ? "<null>" : r.Field<string>("Name").Replace(",", "") into g
        select new
        {
           CallType = g.Key,
           Count = g.Count()
        });
```

For more details checkout following blog:

https://web.archive.org/web/20110521014654/http://infinitecodex.com/post/2010/07/05/LINQ-Group-By-with-NULL-database-values.aspx